# How to include CONNECT_BY_PRIOR into GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select r.*,max(connect_by_root(c_name)) as root , max(level) 
from relat r
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with chld = 'srv'
connect by prior p_name = c_name
group by r.par, r.chld, r.c_name, r.p_name;
```

I want to include `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)` into `GROUP BY` clause instead of using `MAX()` function on it. If I add `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)` into `GROUP BY` clause it throws me error `not a group by expression`. So is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that oracle takes `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)` in `SELECT` clause and `GROUP BY` clause as different columns. And so when I try `group by` it and `select` oracle thinks that I'm grouping by one `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)` column and trying to select another one `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)` column and throws me error `not a group by expression`.
So I came up with this solution:

```
select par, chld, c_name, p_name, root, max(lvl) as lvl
from (select r.*,connect_by_root(c_name) as root, level as lvl
        from relat r
        where connect_by_isleaf = 1
        start with chld = 'srv'
        connect by prior p_name = c_name)
group by par, chld, c_name, p_name, root;
```

I'm doing connect by query first and then group it by the columns I need.

Comment: Please, describe, what `oracle takes each CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name) as different columns` means and why do you think so? I cannot understand current explanation

Comment: @astentx in the `group by` function you cannot select columns which either weren't include in `group by` clause or group functions like `MAX(); AVG()` weren't applied to them. So when I wrote query I included `CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)` into list of columns by which I would like to `group by` like `GROUP BY ...,CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)` and also included it in columns which I want to `select` like `SELECT ...., CONNECT_BY_ROOT(c_name)`. But oracle still has thrown me error. My theory is that oracle takes `COONECT_BY_ROOT` column in the `group by` and `select` clauses as different columns.